# Post numa lista com checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou criando uma aplicação em que o usuário poderá selecionar uma variedade de produtos por meio de `checkbox`. Porém quando clico em "Comprar" a lista vai vazia. Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda com relação a isso?

Esse código é o da View:

```cs
<tbody>
 @foreach (var servico in Model.Servicos)
 {
<tr>
    <td>
        @servico.Descricao_Servico
    </td>
<td>
    @servico.Valor_Servico
</td>
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
        <input type="checkbox"  id="@servico.Id" />
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>  
 }
</tbody>
```

---

Esse próximo é o da controladora

```cs
public ActionResult Cadastrar()
{
    var modelo = ModeloCadastrar();
    return View(modelo);
}

private CadastrarAgendamentoViewModel ModeloCadastrar()
{
    var modelo = new CadastrarAgendamentoViewModel();

    var ddlListaDeFuncionarios = _contexto.Funcionarios.ToList();
    var ddlListaDeServicos = _contexto.Servicos.ToList();
    var ddlProdutos = _contexto.Produtos.ToList();

    modelo.ListaDeFuncionarios = (from funcionarios in ddlListaDeFuncionarios
                                  select new SelectListItem
                                  {
                                      Text = funcionarios.Nome_Usuario,
                                      Value = funcionarios.Id.ToString(),
                                  }).ToList();


    modelo.ListaDeProdutos = (from produtos in ddlProdutos
                              select new SelectListItem
                              {
                                  Text = produtos.Descricao_Produto,
                                  Value = produtos.Id.ToString(),
                              }).ToList();
    modelo.Servicos = ddlListaDeServicos;

    modelo.Data_Agendamento = System.DateTime.Now;
    modelo.Hora_Agendamento = "08:00";
    return modelo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo: [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

*View:*

```cs
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Lista";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
    <h2>Lista</h2>
    <div>
        <label for="Produto1">Produto 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Produto1" name="Produto" value="1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Produto2">Produto 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Produto2" name="Produto" value="2">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Produto3">Produto 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Produto3" name="Produto" value="3">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Produto4">Produto 4</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Produto4" name="Produto" value="4">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>
}
```

*Action:*

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Lista()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Lista(FormCollection form)
{    
    System.Collections.IEnumerable Produto = form["Produto"];
    return RedirectToAction("Lista");
}
```

*Pagina gerada - Html*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Quando clico no botão `Submit` Enviar*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Agora tudo vai depender do seu modelo e regra da sua aplicação*

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro problema é a falta do atributo `name` no *input*. Sem um *name* o *input* não é postado.

Seu checkbox deve ser feito da seguinte forma:

```css
<input type="checkbox" id="@servico.Id" name="Servicos" value="@servico.Id" />
```

Isso já deverá resolver o *post*. Além disso se você espera receber no `controller` um array de serviço, faça da seguinte forma:

```css
<tbody>
 @{
     var i = 0;
 }
 @foreach (var servico in Model.Servicos)
 {
<tr>
    <td>
        @servico.Descricao_Servico
    </td>
<td>
    @servico.Valor_Servico
</td>
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input type="checkbox"  id="@servico.Id" name='@string.format("Servicos[{0}]", i)' value="@servico.Id" />
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
  @{i++;}
 }
</tbody>
```

Dessa forma seu *post* irá enviar um array de *checkboxes* com valores e o `ModelBinder` do Mvc conseguirá criar seu objeto, ou você poderá buscar os valores pelo `formcollection`.

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente não funcionou comigo. Vou te mandar o modelo que eu mando para a view.
`Segue meu modelo:

```
public class CadastrarAgendamentoViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ClienteId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Campo obrigatório")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime Data_Agendamento { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
        public string Hora_Agendamento { get; set; }

        public int Atendido_Agendamento { get; set; }
        public int Id_Cliente { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
        public int Id_Funcionario { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> ListaDeFuncionarios { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> Id_Produto { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> ListaDeProdutos { get; set; }

        public List<T_Servicos> Servicos { get; set; }

        public double Preco_Agendamento { get; set; }

        public bool Sucesso { get; set; }

        public string Mensagem { get; set; }

        public CadastrarAgendamentoViewModel()
        {
            Servicos = new List<T_Servicos>();
        }

        public LayoutHelper helper { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Minha intenção é dispor os checkbox em uma table dinamicamente.

`

Comment: Use o link de edição em sua pergunta para adicionar outras informações. O botão Publicar resposta deve ser usado apenas para concluir respostas à pergunta.